# How to package only the necessary libs in Google App Engine Project(Java)?

Tags: eclipse, maven, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, packaging

Let me explain first what I mean by **necessary** libs. I'm creating my first project using the [Google App Engine for Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/) with the official [Google Maven Plugin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven), the main problem that have Maven as a packaging solution (or maybe the Java development as a whole) is that if the dependency tree grows *too much*, the release process may be harder.

Let me illustrate it with an example. Let's start with the Jackson JSON library (it's a good starting point since it has no parent dependencies), now someone makes a JSON-RPC library and uses Jackson for the JSON serialization/deserialization. Imagine that this library not just provides a JSON-RPC client implementation, but also a server, that means that the POM of this lib will add some Java EE related libraries such us Jetty as dependencies.

Probably the guidelines say that the application should be either divided into modules or mark the server related deps as optional, but you know that many people don't follow the standards.

Now someone need a JSON-RPC client for his/her project, call it Project X, and uses the lib mentioned above, at compile time there will be no problems, Maven will successfully download the required libs and the application will compile fine, but the problem comes when that person wants to release the application. **Which dependencies** should be distributed along with the package (in a lib folder for example)?

Actually that's something that happened to me, I wasn't too much familiar with Maven so I used the [Eclipse Runnable Jar Exporter](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-export-runnable-jar.htm), that produced jar file with all the maven libs copied to a lb subfolder, so the workaround that I did then was to just delete the libs that *looked unnecessary* and then tested if the application was still working. If there are classes that are not executed, as far as I know they are not loaded by the `ClassLoader` so they could be omitted and are unnecessary

I can't use the same trick now since the scenario is much more complex, we are talking of a Java Web Application, not a desktop application like the other one, and the library that I want to include is a [Liquid](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers) Template [Engine](https://github.com/bkiers/Liqp), which uses the [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) framework to generate the parsers plus Jackson for the JSON handler and Jsoup for HTML parsing.

Which libs should be packaged inside the WEB-INF/lib folder? I'm sure that I will need Jackson for JSON parsing but I'm not so sure about Jsoup, and what about ANTLR, it is necessary or is used just at compile time?

**Update:** I think I need to re-formulate my question, actually what I want is to **determine** which dependencies are really necessary for the application, and package those into the app WEB-INF/lib folder

**Solution:** It seems that the POM file that is packaged in the WAR file of the web app is *used* once the app is in the Google App Engine production environment to retrieve the necessary dependencies, and probably the `appengine:update` goal only packages those dependencies that can't be retrieved from the maven central repo, so there is no need to worry about that.

Thanks to [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1654764/david) to point this.

Comment: Is your question "how can I be sure not to accidentally omit transitive dependencies from my packaged application" or "how can I exclude unused transitive dependencies from my packaged application"?  I infer that it's the latter; in that case, have a look at ProGuard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check Maven's [dependency scopes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope). Here's an extract from the documentation :

> There are 6 scopes available:
>
> - **compile** This is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile
>     dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project.
>     Furthermore, those dependencies are propagated to dependent projects.
> - **provided** This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK
>     or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when
>     building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would
>     set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to
>     scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This
>     scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is
>     not transitive.
> - **runtime** This scope indicates that the dependency is
>     not required for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the
>     runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath.
> - **test** This
>     scope indicates that the dependency is not required for normal use of
>     the application, and is only available for the test compilation and
>     execution phases.
> - **system** This scope is similar to provided except that
>     you have to provide the JAR which contains it explicitly. The artifact
>     is always available and is not looked up in a repository.
> - **import** (only
>     available in Maven 2.0.9 or later) This scope is only used on a
>     dependency of type pom in the  section. It
>     indicates that the specified POM should be replaced with the
>     dependencies in that POM's  section. Since they
>     are replaced, dependencies with a scope of import do not actually
>     participate in limiting the transitivity of a dependency.

So in a Maven project, the developer indicates which dependencies should be bundled in the application and which should not.

Basically there are two cases here :

- If you're building a web application (WAR or EAR format) and want to deploy it, or if you're building an actual runnable jar, then you will need to bundle it with all the dependencies with scope `compile` and `runtime`.
- If you're building a library, then **you do not package any dependency** with your library. Instead you include the `pom.xml` so that others know what dependency your library requires. For Maven to know how to find the associated POM for a given jar, the best and most common solution is to deploy the library to a Maven repository. Repos have a directory structure that helps Maven find the right version of a library, and find the POM that indicates the required dependencies.

Depending on wether your library is open source or not, you will be able to be hosted for free by some repositories such as Sonatype ([complete list here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html)). But you can also setup your own repository either by installing a dedicated software such as [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) or by configuring a Github project as the repo, [as is explained on this blog](http://cemerick.com/2010/08/24/hosting-maven-repos-on-github/).

Comment: Thanks! In my case I need to deploy it to war since that's the format that uses the Google App Engine. But I really need to package all the dependencies on the compile and runtime scopes? Could that be achieved with the `copy-dependencies` plugin?

Comment: It is automatically done for you ! If you run `mvn appengine:update` or `mvn package` all the dependencies that you declared in the `pom.xml` will automatically be added.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude any transitive dependency.

For your case, to remove jetty from this json-rpc-library, you need:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.somecomp</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsonrpclib</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

See docs: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Comment: Maybe I didn't make it clear but, that was just an example for illustration purposes, the library that I want to use is [this](https://github.com/bkiers/Liqp) and by default that artifact is the only one that is packaged in the WEB-INF/lib, but I need also Jackson and to be packaged, as well as other libs probably

Comment: it's just example. with this syntax you could include only what you need, and exclude what don't need. or it's not enough?

Comment: @igor-artmonov The problem is not excluding dependencies, the problem is that it doesn't package the dependencies from the upper tree(Jackson, Jsoup)

Comment: I have re-formulated my question in an update, check it out and let's if you can help me

Comment: I don't think there is a way to determine which library is actually used, don't think that can be done automatically, too many possible cases that could break it